# concatenate rows on dataframe one by one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have 2 dataframes

```
df1:
  data  type
0    a     1
1    b     1
2    c     1
3    d     1
4    e     1

df2:
  data  type
0    v     2
1    w     2
2    x     2
3    y     2
4    z     2 

arr = [['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['c', 1], ['d', 1], ['e', 1]]
arr2 = [['v', 2], ['w', 2], ['x', 2], ['y', 2], ['z', 2]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['data', 'type'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(arr2, columns=['data', 'type'])
```

I want to concat and make dataframe which is like shuffled in pattern 1st is type one, 2nd type 2 .....

**expected output:**

```
  data  type
0    a     1
1    v     2
2    b     1
3    w     2
4    c     1
5    x     2
6    d     1
7    y     2
8    e     1
9    z     2
```

**Constrains**: if for example df1 has more rows then df2 then output be like

```
   data  type
0     a     1
1     v     2
2     b     1
3     w     2
4     c     1
5     x     2
6     d     1
7     y     2
8     e     1
9     z     2
10    f     1
11    g     1
12    h     1
```

and visa versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to change the indices of your input dataframes. Then concatenate and sort by index. This will also handle situations where your dataframes have mismatched lengths.

```
df1.index = df1.index*2
df2.index = df2.index*2 + 1

res = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()

print(res)

  data  type
0    a     1
1    v     2
2    b     1
3    w     2
4    c     1
5    x     2
6    d     1
7    y     2
8    e     1
9    z     2
```

If you need to normalize your index when your dataframes have inconsistent lengths, you can use `reset_index` as a final step:

```
res = res.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an extra column with even and odd index in both dataframes, and the concat and sort it. It will preserve the original index of both dataframes.

```
arr = [['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['c', 1], ['d', 1], ['e', 1]]
arr2 = [['v', 2], ['w', 2], ['x', 2], ['y', 2], ['z', 2]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['data', 'type'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(arr2, columns=['data', 'type'])

df1['temp'] = range(0, 2*df1.shape[0], 2)  # add even index
df2['temp'] = range(1, 2*df2.shape[0], 2)  # add odd index
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values('temp').drop('temp', axis=1)

print (df)

  data  type
0    a     1
0    v     2
1    b     1
1    w     2
2    c     1
2    x     2
3    d     1
3    y     2
4    e     1
4    z     2
```